# Zeus Trojan's Source Code

Tags: virus, trojan

I am not sure if this is the correct platform for this question. The source code of Zeus trojan is available on the internet. It can be found on github as well. I have read somewhere that the purpose is to make research easier to understand how something like this works.

My questions are:

1. How was the source code found? The original author can't have given it out.
2. Is it possible that a person can make a new trojan or virus from such source code which will not get detected by an antivirus? If so, why was release of this source code allowed?

Comment: "The original author can't have given it out." Why not? Seems like a good way to hide your tracks after you've made your money.

Comment: [Renaming is a common AV bypass technique.](https://www.blackhillsinfosec.com/bypass-anti-virus-run-mimikatz/)